# Integral Calculus Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: integration

I am not sure where this question came from, its on my study sheet and hit me out of nowhere,

The question is

if $$f(x) = \int_0^{x^3} cos(t^2)\,dt$$

find $f'(x)$

Now, i am not sure if this is actually FTC, I just have never seen a question like this before

Comment: This is probably a typo, but this integral does not mean anything, and there is no $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus states:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $x\in[a,b]$, then if $$g(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt,$$ then $g'(x)=f(x)$.

To solve your problem, let $g(x)=\int_0^x\cos(t^2)\,dt$. You are looking for the derivative of $g(x^3)$. Use the chain rule to see that $$\frac{d}{dx}g(x^3)=3x^2g'(x^3).$$ Now use FTC to rewrite $g'(x^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using fundamental theorem of calculus and derivative of composite function you'll have
$$
f'(x)=\cos(t^2)\big|_{t=x^3}(x^3)'=3x^2 \cos(x^6)
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $$g(s) = \int_0^{s} cos(t^2)\,dt$$

so $f(x)=g(x^3) $ than use the Chain-Role